# How to get an array with modulus from array with complex numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I I have a problem with visualization of array with complex number. I need to have an array with modulus of complex numbers to make a plot, but i do not know how to do it using numpy. What can i do?

Comment: Are you looking for `mod = np.abs(complex_array)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `m` is an array of complex numbers, you can get the modulus of each element with `numpy.abs(m)`

As an example:

```
>>> m=np.random.random((2,2))+np.random.random((2,2))*1j
>>> m
array([[ 0.95274284+0.39078475j,  0.80123497+0.10182257j],
   [ 0.50777149+0.41198386j,  0.83248958+0.20489083j]])
>>> numpy.abs(m)
array([[ 1.02977262,  0.80767896],
   [ 0.65388271,  0.85733258]])
```